# find min and max of each column in pandas without min and max of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as shown below.

[image]

I need to find the min and max of each column.The code I used is given below.

```
df_thd_funct_mode1_T.agg([min, max])
```

and the output obtained is given below.

[image]

You can see that the min and max of index is also came there.I don't need that.So I changed my code as shown.

```
df_thd_funct_mode1_T.agg([min, max],axis="columns")
```

but it is throwing some error as shown. May I know where I went wrong

**ValueError: no results**

Comment: Just for the record, that's not an index.  That's a plain, ordinary column that happens to be called "index".  Did you intend that to be the index of the DataFrame?

Comment: Your correct.I don't need the min and max of that.I need the min and max of remaining columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just select from the second column of the result and save it in a new dataframe.

```
df_thd_funct_mode1_T.agg([min,max]).iloc[:,1:]
```

to save it to a new df:

```
new_df = df_thd_funct_mode1_T.agg([min,max]).iloc[:,1:]
```

Comment: I tried to include mean and standard deviation .agg([min,mean,max,std]).iloc[:,1:] .It is throwing an error: name 'mean' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

```
df_thd_funct_mode1_T.set_index('index').agg([min, max])
```